# Why request.get() is giving me an error in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
url="https://beta.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
requests.get(url)
```

I am using requests but it is giving me a timeout error..but when i open same link in browser its working fine

Comment: You probably need some headers which are present when you use your browser. Have you tried tracing the interactions from your browser using e.g. Telerik Fiddler, and comparing with the interactions when your Python code interacts with the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with some user agent string header:

```
import requests
url="https://beta.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


>>> response
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

`beta.nseindia.com/` has a policy which blocks the request coming from bot.

Comment: I had experienced the same issue in the past with this site, hence I was aware of what header to use.

Comment: What I was trying to get you to explain is _how_ you discovered that the header is needed. Or if you didn’t discover it is needed, how did the person who _did_ discover it is needed do that discovery?

Comment: I think @barny has brought up a great point. Learning how to think and solve problems is infinitely more important than just copy/pasting a solution that someone else also just copy/pasted.

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll all the way up through your errors you will see an **`InsecureRequestWarning`**, meaning you were making an unverified HTTPS request. This can be resolved by following [this](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl) guide.

First, you need to install some packages to handle the certificates:

```
pip install certifi pip urllib3[secure]
```

Then, in your code you create a **`PoolManager`** that verifies certificates when making requests:

```
import requests
import certifi
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
url = 'https://beta.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'

http.request('GET', url, verify=False)
```

Depending on which version of python you are using this might or might not work.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant parts of the link in your answer?